# Android: How to check internet connectivity on API level 29 or higher in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, connectivity

Before i was using these few lines of codes to check if the device is connected to the internet or not:

```
fun isOnline(): Boolean {
    val cm = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val netInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
}
```

But `getActiveNetworkInfo()` was deprecated in Android 10 and official documentation is suggesting to use  `NetworkCallbacks` instead for apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) and higher.
So here's the problem, i didn't find any resources that might help to implement the `NetworkCallbacks` except the one here: [on medium.com](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-check-internet-connection-on-android-q-ea7c5a103e3). But it's too complicated.
Is there any better or simpler way to implement this or i must go through the whole lengthy process?

Answer (score 3):

You can use NetworkCapablities class for checking internet connectivity before making the network request.

```
fun internetCheck(c: Context): Boolean {
        val cmg = c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            // Android 10+
            cmg.getNetworkCapabilities(cmg.activeNetwork)?.let { networkCapabilities ->
                return networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                        || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            }
        } else {
            return cmg.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true
        }

        return false
    }
```

But if your activity needs to listen to Network connectivity changes, you should implement NetworkCallbacks.

Comment: I will accept this answer if you guys can tell me if there's other possible network providers other than `TRANSPORT_CELLULAR`, `TRANSPORT_WIFI` and `TRANSPORT_ETHERNET`? Because i don't want to give the user "No Internet Warning" when he have internet connection.

Comment: @Junior Here is a list with al the types - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH

Answer (score 1):

You can check it by getting all networks with `getAllNetworks()` and loop through each of them to see if any is connected.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
fun isOnline(): Boolean {

    val connectivityMgr = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    
    val allNetworks: Array<Network> = connectivityMgr.allNetworks // added in API 21 (Lollipop)
        
        for (network in allNetworks) {
            val networkCapabilities = connectivityMgr!!.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
             return (networkCapabilities!!.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) &&
                    networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED) &&
                    (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                            || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                            || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)))
        }

    }
    return false
}
```

Also add the below permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**UPDATE**

> Can you tell me some other possible internet providers other than TRANSPORT_CELLULAR, TRANSPORT_WIFI and TRANSPORT_ETHERNET?

The answer to this can change over time; although, to the date, these transport technologies are sufficient for accessing the internet on mobile sets in terms of the technology capabilities provided nowadays.

Although there are other transport methods that might be utilized by device manufactures in the future.

For instance: [`TRANSPORT_WIFI_AWARE`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-aware) which is a technology that enable devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher to discover and connect directly to each other without any other type of connectivity between them. So, it's a transport method between devices over the Wi-Fi; but so far it doesn't pass internet between devices; maybe that can be used in the future.

Similarly, [`TRANSPORT_LOWPAN`](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/apis/lowpan) allows Android devices to communicate directly with other peer devices, even ultra-low power battery operated nodes that may not have WiFi or Bluetooth connectivity (such as door locks and window sensors). Again today `TRANSPORT_LOWPAN` doesn't pass the internet between those devices, but it facilitates the communication locally among them.

`TRANSPORT_VPN` Allows the communication between devices over a private network which should be explicitly coded by you; unless you do that, you don't have to use it to check the internet availability.

Comment: Can you tell me some other possible internet providers other than `TRANSPORT_CELLULAR`, `TRANSPORT_WIFI` and `TRANSPORT_ETHERNET`?

Answer (score 0):

you Can create an extension like this

```
fun Context.isOnline(): Boolean {
    return try {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val netInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
        netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected
    } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        false
    }
}
```

And create **BroadcastReceiver** like this

```
class Connection : BroadcastReceiver() {

    lateinit var dialog: Dialog

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        dialog = Dialog(context)

        dialog.apply {
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog_connection)
            setCancelable(false)
            window!!.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
            window!!.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
            window!!.attributes.windowAnimations = R.style.AnimationPopup


        }

        check(context = context) {
            if (!it) {
                dialog.show()
            } else {
                dialog.cancel()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun check(context: Context, result: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
        try {
            if (context.isOnline()) {
                result(true)
            } else {
                result(false)
            }

        } catch (e: java.lang.NullPointerException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
    Network currentNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();

    if(currentNetwork==null){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }


}
```